# Python: Grouping numbers that are within n SD of central value for the group

Tags: python, list

I have a list of multiple floats that looks something like this

```
mylist = [10, 10.2, 10.5, 11, 15, 15.3, 15.4, 16, 27, 27.4, 28, 28.1, 28.2]
```

I want to group the values that are close to each other. For eg. I want to group values from 10 to 11 into the average of the 4 values. I am having a hard time identifying the central values and then selecting values to left and right that would fall in the group. How could I do this?

Comment: This list seems to be a sorted list. Correct? Also, you wanted to group floatings betweeb two integers?

Comment: if you know the number of groups, k-means algorithm would be useful. check [sklearn.cluster.KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

How about this using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: group = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: mylist = [10, 10.2, 10.5, 11, 15, 15.3, 15.4, 16, 27, 27.4, 28, 28.1, 28
   ...: .2]

In [4]: for val in mylist:
   ...:     group[int(val)].append(val)
   ...:     

In [5]: group
Out[5]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {10: [10, 10.2, 10.5],
             11: [11],
             15: [15, 15.3, 15.4],
             16: [16],
             27: [27, 27.4],
             28: [28, 28.1, 28.2]})
```

It does not need sorted input. Also, it preserves the order of related values

assuming, I correctly understand your requirement.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. It serves as a great starting point. However, I'd like to have group values from 10-11 in 1 group. Defaultdict is grouping them to the nearest int value less than the float. It messes up certain values (11,16)

Comment: Lets say i want to pool data points that are +/- 0.5 from the central value in the pool. Now I want to identify the best central points in my data, which here would be 10.5 (that pools values from 10 to 11), 15.5 (15 - 16) and 27.8 (27.3 to 28.3). In this exercise 27 does not fall in any pool.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you want a general method, probably something like:

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

data = [10, 10.2, 10.5, 11, 15, 15.3, 15.4, 16, 27, 27.4, 28, 28.1, 28.2]
stats, edges, binarray = binned_statistic(data,data,bins=4)

edges    # Is the boundary values that split the data evenly into 4 bins. 
binarray # Shows which numbers in your original array belong to which equal sized bin. 
         # Note that nothing belongs to bin-3 because the gap is too wide.
```